# Distribute a java web application using windows installer

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, windows-installer, jetty

I have a web application packaged in standard WAR format, and we'd like to distribute it using a "normal" windows installer for user-friendliness.

The application can be adapted to run in an embedded servlet container such as embedded tomcat or jetty, if that simplifies the problem.

The preferred solution should (bonus points, from the most important to the least important):

- install the application or the servlet container as a windows service (when computer starts, the servlet container starts)
- install JRE as well
- install other programs (for example postgresql)
- allow automation (be it ant, maven, gradle)

Running the servlet container on port 80 is not mandatory, so installing the whole app in non privileged enviroments is an option

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)** which is a professional open source system to create Windows installers.

You can find more information here : [nsis.sourceforge.net](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

Although this is very old solution and programming in NSIS is a bit difficult but it is still being used if you are looking a free solution.